# How could i convert a maya file into a json file and use it with three.js

Tags: json, three.js, maya

I want to use some maya files in my three.js project,but it seems like only the json files can be used in three.js

So how can i convert those files?

thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please have a look at the [three.js Maya exporter](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters/maya).

The scripts should be in `your three.js folder/ utils / exporters / maya`