# How to convert object to json file for three.js model loader

Tags: python, json, three.js, maya

I am building a browser game with `three.js` and I want to load a model from Maya 2013 into my scene. I have exported the model as an obj file.

Now I need to know how to convert it into an JS file for the `three.js`-loader.

This is my loader so far:

```
 var jsonLoader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
 jsonLoader.load( "models/model.js", addModelToScene );
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How could i convert a maya file into a json file and use it with three.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14919219/how-could-i-convert-a-maya-file-into-a-json-file-and-use-it-with-three-js) ...straight from the sidebar.

Comment: or, since you have converted it to obj, you can use the OBJLoader or OBJMTLLoader to load it straight into three.js

Comment: ive tried the OBJLoader bt i get a Type Error: THREE.MTLLoader is not a costructor. But OBJLoader is included

Comment: You need to include MTLLoader.js as well.

Comment: i have included these two: <script src="js/OBJLoader.js"></script>
<script src="js/OBJMTLLoader.js"></script>

Comment: You need to include MTLLoader.js as well.

Comment: Using the OBJloader & MTLloader is not an optimal solution, as the application must parse the geometry every time it is loaded. Currently, I'm trying (& trying) to get Blender to recognize the exporter addon, (still greyed out in the addons list.)

Answer (score 13):

If you don't want to use blender, mrdoob(made threejs) has a simple python script to convert obj to json. Just run [--this script--](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/utils/converters/obj/convert_obj_three.py) in terminal like so:

```
python convert_obj_three.py -i infile.obj -o outfile.js
```

Comment: Any idea on how to automate this? It's teadious work to export even a few models.

Answer (score 11):

Use Blender.

[Blender 3D](http://www.blender.org/)

Then install this addon:

[Three.js exporter](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters/blender)

Answer (score 6):

Thats a pretty late reply. I have written a converter to read obj files and convert to ThreeJS supported JSON format:
https://github.com/theMaxscriptGuy/Windows_Programs/tree/master/Obj_To_ThreeJS

Download all the files as zip and run converter.exe...

Comment: I've tried it on windows 8 but it doesn't work. Have you tested it ?

Comment: Hey, I have not been able to test it on windows 8. Can you plese share the issue/screenshot.

Comment: Unfortunately, after a lot of experimenting with various workflows I found out that the vertex normals exported using converter.exe don't always match the .3ds file. I was using the `vertexNormalsHelper` to check for defects. However what works for sure is the `convert_obj_three.py` python script. It seems to give the expected results.

Answer (score 6):

Note: the python converter script has been updated to a js based tool https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/utils/converters

Usage:

`node obj2three.js model.obj`

Answer (score 3):

When exporting 3ds max models to three.js using the `[convert_obj_three.py][1]` script, a little degree of automation can be achieved with the following command in cmd promt:

```
cd C:\Python27 &
python convert_obj_three.py -i _obj\chromeBand.obj -o _json\chromeBand.js &
python convert_obj_three.py -i _obj\controlPanelCover.obj -o _json\controlPanelCover.js
```

I wrote a 3ds max script that will print the phyton script command for multiple models and also a json with the models relative urls and coordinates. The json is useful for placing multiple models at the correct position in scene.

```
(
local inputPath = "D:\Archive\Work\_Dev\_Convert\Obj\\"
local outputPath = "C:\Server\htdocs\viewer\assets\models\my-project\\"
local jsonPath = "assets/models/my-project/"
local myListEntry = "\n"

for o in selection do
    (
        myListEntry +=
        "\"" + o.name + "\": {\n" +
            "\t\"url\": \"" + jsonPath + o.name + ".js\",\n" +
            "\t\"position\": {\n" +
                "\t\t\"x\": \"" + o.position.x as string + "\",\n" +
                "\t\t\"y\": \"" + o.position.z as string + "\",\n" +
                "\t\t\"z\": \"" + (o.position.y * -1) as string + "\"\n" +
            "\t}\n" +
        "},\n"
    )

myListEntry += "\n\n\n=== Run this using cmd promt: ===\n"
myListEntry += "cd C:\Python27 &\n"

for o in selection do
    (
        myListEntry += "python D:\Archive\Work\_Dev\_Convert\convert_obj_three.py -i " + 
            inputPath + o.name + ".obj -o " + 
            outputPath + o.name + ".js & \n"
    )

myListEntry += "exit \n"
print myListEntry
actionMan.executeAction 0 "40472"
)
```

- Create a new txt file, rename it to `coordinates.mcr` and drag and drop the file into the 3ds max window. It will automatically open MaxScript Listener window and print the results. Copy paste the python command in cmd. Use the printed json to batch load your models in your project.
- Also, scripts can be assigned to buttons in 3dsMax toolbars, for fast access.
- The above script could use further tweaking. Not the best solution but at least it speeds up things, hopefuly.
- Use Jos Balcaen's script for [exporting obj files in batch](http://josbalcaen.com/scripts/max/batch-exportimport/) (3ds Max)

**Edit:**

After experimenting a bit with the script I have made a setup that allows me to export my models (counting more than 20) in under 1 minute from 3ds max to open browser tab. Of course, you may need to adjust the json output to your liking. Hope you will find this useful.

Answer (score 2):

Create a Python file named `conversion.py`. [Click here to find out how to](https://github.com/timoxley/threejs/blob/master/utils/exporters/obj/convert_obj_three.py).

Then execute the following command in your Terminal:

```
python conversion.py -i file.obj -o file.js
```